# how to get docker images details that are built using fabric8 maven plugin?

Tags: maven, docker, fabric8, docker-build

In our project we create docker images, push to registry using `fabric8` maven plugin. We have a requirement in which we need to find out the details of each image (name, tag , registry pushed to etc) that gets created in the project build.
Is there any out of the box solution in `fabric8` for that ? or do we have any java API's of `fabric8` available which we can use and integrate in our existing maven plugin to get such info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get such info from the plugin itself. But when building Docker images with `fabric8`'s `docker-maven-plugin`, a hierarchy like the following is created on the `target/` folder by default :

```
target
├── docker
│   ├── build.timestamp
│   └── my
│       └── registry
│           ├── image1
│           │   ├── tag1
│           │   │   ├── build
│           │   │   │   └── Dockerfile
│           │   │   ├── tmp
│           │   │   │   └── docker-build.tar
│           │   │   └── work
│           │   └── tag2
│           │       ├── build
│           │       │   └── Dockerfile
│           │       ├── tmp
│           │       │   └── docker-build.tar
│           │       └── work
│           ├── image2
│           │   ├── tag1
│           │   │   ├── ...
...         ... ... ...
```

In this example, 3 images were built :

- `my/registry/image1:tag1`
- `my/registry/image1:tag2`
- `my/registry/image2:tag1`

So browsing this hierarchy can inform you about the images names, tags and registries. I agree that it is not the cleanest solution.

Alternatively, you can use `spotify`'s `dockerfile-maven-plugin` (https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven), because it creates a `docker-info` JAR containing what you're looking for :

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/docker/
META-INF/docker/my/registry/
META-INF/docker/my/registry/image1/
META-INF/docker/my/registry/image1/image-name
META-INF/docker/my/registry/image1/repository
META-INF/docker/my/registry/image1/tag
META-INF/docker/my/registry/image1/image-id
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/my/registry/
META-INF/maven/my/registry/image1/
META-INF/maven/my/registry/image1/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/my/registry/image1/pom.properties
```

This `docker-info` JAR could then be put into a repository manager to help retrieving information about built images, and moreover to version your different builds.